# Please Wait... When trying to edit a large Categories' name?

Tags: category, save

I'm editing a bunch of categories for this Magento site and I am hitting a wall.

I'm only trying to change the Name, the status of the Is Active and the Includes in Navigation Menu.

On the categories that contain a low amount of products, it works fine, updates within a few seconds..

On the categories with say over 100 products, it seems to be stuck on a 'Please Wait..' pop up box screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When editing products and categories the indexes are rebuilt for the entities you edit. This takes a lot of time specially for rebuilding category-product associations.

Go to `System->Index Management` and set the mode for all your indexes to `manual`.
Then do your changes and rebuild the indexes manually.

When you're done you can set the mode for the indexes back to `update on save`.

Comment: Should indexes be changed back to 'on save' before manually reindexing to catch any changes between the two operations? Just a thought.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your statement, but I don't think it's important if you change the mode to `on save` before or after you rebuild the indexes. The idea is to have them on `manual` as long as you do heavy changes for the category tree.

Comment: Thankyou mate, this worked for me