# "Please wait" sign comes up when working with categories in Admin - and stays for a long time

Tags: magento-1.9, category

```
Magento 1.9.1
Porto theme
Amasty's Full Page Cache
```

When going into `Catalog --) Categories` and trying to do something like move a category what happens is - the "**Please wait**" sign comes up with the circle and it takes almost 5 minutes before it goes away. It now seems to do what it suppose to and unfreezes the screen after those 5 minutes. Yesterday, it would completely freeze the screen I think.

I was getting Error messages when doing this exact thing about 3 days ago:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction, query was: INSERT INTO `mg_index_process_event` (`process_id`,`event_id`,`status`) VALUES (?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `status` = VALUES(`status`)


SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction, query was: UPDATE `mg_catalog_category_entity` SET `entity_type_id` = ?, `attribute_set_id` = ?, `parent_id` = ?, `created_at` = '2015-05-29 03:04:01', `updated_at` = '2017-09-12 15:01:17', `path` = ?, `position` = ?, `level` = ?, `children_count` = ? WHERE (`entity_id`=111)


SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction, query was: INSERT INTO `mg_index_process_event` (`process_id`,`event_id`,`status`) VALUES (?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `status` = VALUES(`status`)
```

*I cleared all Cache and re-indexed. Also restarted mySQL and Apache but it did not help.*

Comment: I think your  `patch security` updating

Comment: Ramesh S: What does that mean?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32123788/cant-add-category-to-fresh-magento-site-please-wait-and-frameception pls refere this link

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/83172/please-wait-when-trying-to-edit-a-large-categories-name  pls refere this link

Comment: Ramesh S: I've already done that (set the mode for all my indexes to 'manual') but does not seem to fix the problem - I think it's just a work-around? Not to mention I have to re-index all the time now...Is there any way to actually fix this problem?

Comment: paste your code here https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65646/discussion-between-ramesh-s-and-stordon

Answer (score 0):

Since you already set your indexers to manual i would say have cron setup to reindex the site in the early morning that way you do not have to reindex as much.

```
0 6 * * * php -f path/to/shell/indexer.php reindexall
```

You would have something similar to this in your cron jobs.

Comment: danmentzer: How would I do that? Any idea why it just started to act the way it does now even though it worked properly before?

Comment: allysin: you should be able to set up a cron job for it in your cpanel for your server.
I will update my answer with an example.

Comment: allysin: If you need more info for setting this up I can provide references as well